# codeigniter - trying to get data from database then send sms

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this send SMS button and when I click it the info of my customer will show in the SENDSMS view and I have no problem with that but when I click the SEND button my program shows me these errors.

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: result
>
> Filename: item/sms.php
>
> Line Number: 15
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: item/sms.php
>
> Line Number: 15

**Line 15 of my sms view code:**

```
  <div class="form-group">
             <label>
                First Name
            </label> 
<input type="text" name="name" class ="form-control" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $result->first_name?>"  >

        </div>
```

**Controller code:**

```
 function sendsms($id){
   $this->load->model('Product_model');
   $result = $this->Product_model->edit_recc($id);
   $this->load->view('admin/item/sms',['result'=>$result]);
   }



 function sending($id){
  $this->load->helper('db_helper');
   if ($_POST) {
   $number = $_POST['number'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $msg = $_POST['msg'];
   $api = "TR-KAMA-----";
   $text = $name.":".$msg;

 if (!empty( $_POST['number']) && ( $_POST['name']) && ( $_POST['msg'])) {
     $result = itexmo($number,$text,$api);
 if ($result == ""){
       echo "iTexMo: No response from server!!!
       Please check the METHOD used (CURL or CURL-LESS). If you are using 
       CURL then try CURL-LESS and vice versa.  
        Please CONTACT US for help. ";  
  }

      else if ($result == 0){
      $this->session->set_flashdata('fail_login', 'Message Sent');
      return redirect ('uploads/sendings');
  }
 else { 
     echo "Error Num ". $result . " was encountered!";
    } 
     }
   function sendings(){
   $this->load->view('admin/item/sms');
   }
```

**Model code:**

```
       function edit_recc($id){
         $qry = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->where('id',$id)
                    ->get('user_upload');
                     return $qry->row();

}
```

What I actually want to do is that when I hit the send button it will send a SMS to my sender. I can send the sms but those blocks of errors are also showing

Comment: be more precise show controllers'code also

Comment: did every print your $result variable? then you can understand that its object or array.

Comment: this is because passing $result to sms view is either empty or not an object

Comment: Check if `$result` is set or not

Comment: @chari try echo code like this echo $result['first_name'];

Comment: I've already tried the $result['first_name']; and it works  but I'm still getting the undefined variable error

Comment: you will always get this error until or unless you properly set check for the result data , see my answer

Comment: Did you have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999692/codeigniter-trying-to-get-data-from-database-then-send-sms/50000532#50000532 if correct don't forget to accept

Answer (score 0):

$result variable is not set, thats why getting error. When sms is sent you need to set variable to sent or ok whatever you want.

Comment: I think your query doesn't return any row, thats why your variable remained undefined. Need to see your query if there's anything missing like wrong selection etc.

Comment: Can you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

The `function sendsms()` has a view where you passed data

> How ever you have not passed any data into the view on `function sendings()`

Which has the same view.

```
$this->load->view('admin/item/sms');
```

Comment: can you give me an example please?